# How send request with query parameter "test[]=test" in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, replace, spring-resttemplate

I need to send get request to `example.com/api` with query param named `test[]`
For this i use spring rest tepmlate

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromUriString(example.com/api)
                .queryParam(test[], "test");

responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.GET,
                    new HttpEntity<>(this.setHttpHeader()),
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyDTO>>() {
                    });
```

But `builder.toUriString()` return `example.com/api?test%5B%5D=test`
I try to replace srting with my method

```
private String repairUri(String uri) {
        return url.replaceAll("%5B%5D", "[]");
    }
```

and call

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(repairUri(builder.toUriString()), HttpMethod.GET,
                    new HttpEntity<>(this.setHttpHeader()),
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyDTO>>() {
                    });
```

But into restTemplate.exchange() this uri convert to `example.com/api?test%5B%5D=test` again.

Meanwhile i easy send `example.com/api?test[]=test` request by POSTMan and it's work.

How Can i send request to `example.com/api?test[]=test` in Spring?

Comment: ..spring does well. It is called ["url encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is "standrad"/recommendation for URL/I/N s.

Comment: Misnamed method: `setHttpHeader()` should be `getHttpHeaders()`, i.e. `get`, not `set`, and plural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find one solution.
In my restTemplate bean definition I add this settings:

```
public RestTemplate myRestTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = restTemplate(timeout);

    DefaultUriBuilderFactory builderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory();
    builderFactory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.VALUES_ONLY);
    restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(builderFactory);
    restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new RestClientResponseExceptionHandler());

    return restTemplate;
}
```

In this [page](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20750) some guys says that `DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE` is also suitable.
Read more in [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `repairUri` method to this when you call `restTemplate.exchange` to this :

```
responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URLDecoder.decode(builder.toUriString(), "UTF-8"), HttpMethod.GET,
                new HttpEntity<>(this.setHttpHeader()),
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyDTO>>() {
                });
```

Comment: Thank you for advice, it's good. But inside `restTemplate.exchange` uri `example.com/api?test[]=test` still converted to `example.com/api?test%5B%5D=test`